# How to preserve file mtime when uploading with Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib, filemtime

I am working on a Python tool to synchronize files between my local machines and a remote server. When I upload a file to the server the modification time property of that file on the server is set to the time of the upload process and not to the `mtime` of the source file, which I want to preserve. I am using `FTP.storbinary()` from the Python `ftplib` to perform the upload. My question: Is there a simple way to preserve the `mtime` when uploading or to set it after the upload? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. The Python ftplib module offers no option to transport the time of the file. Furthermore, the FTP protocol as defined by [rfc-959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) has no provision to directly get not set the mtime of a file. It may be possible on some servers through `SITE` commands, but this is server dependant.

If it is possible for you, you should be able to pass a site command with the `sendcmd` method of a connection object. For example if the server accepts a special `SITE SETDATE filename iso-8601-date-string` you could use:

```
resp = ftp.sendcmd(f'SITE SETDATE {file_name} {date-string}')
```

Comment: `ftplib.error_perm: 500 'SITE SETDATE' not understood` :-(

Comment: @atarax42 `SITE HELP` or `HELP SITE` could give the list of the SITE commands that the server can understand.

Comment: The following `SITE` commands are recognized: `QUOTA`, The following `SITE` extensions are recognized: `RATIO`, `HELP`, `CHGRP`, `CHMOD`

Comment: @atarax42 Then I am afraid that your server has no support for getting nor setting the mtime of a file...

Comment: But the `FEAT` command revealed the support for the `MFMT` (modify modification time) command that is precisely what I was looking for.  I tested it and it worked. Scheme: `ftp.sendcmd(f'MFMT {date_string} {file_name}')`